# Azure functions NCRONTAB: Don´t trigger a timetrigger on saturdays

Tags: azure-functions

Trying to set up a Timetrigger function and got stuck with the NCRONTAB-expression. How do i set up the expression so the function triggers every morning at 05.00 AM but not at saturdays. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NCRONTAB expressions are based on this format:

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

Have you tried something like this:

```
0 0 5 * * 0-5
```

This would run the job at 05:00:00 - and on every weekend (1-5) plus Sunday (0). Saturday (which is day #6) is excluded like this